# the findOne function dose not work in this code

Tags: api, authentication

I have this issue that findOne dosnt work, I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
import express from 'express'
import path from 'path'
import mongoose from "mongoose"
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import auth from "./auth";






const app=express()


app.use(bodyParser.json())

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/shoppinglist',{useMongoClient:true})


app.use("/api/auth",auth)
```

```
import express from "express";
import User from './User'


const router = express.Router();


router.post("/",function(req, res) {




        User.findOne({username: req.body.credentials.username},(user)=>{
            if (!user) {
                  res.status(400).json({ errors: { global: "really???!!!" } });
            }})




  });
  export default router;
```

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
   username:String,

}   

  );

  module.exports = mongoose.model("User", schema);
```

any suggestion? the code pick the req.body.username but the findOne dosnt check the user. I am guessing I am making some mistake on the User.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback parameters are incorrect. The callback accepts two parameters: err and document. In your case the parameter `err` is missing Try this.

```
User.findOne({username: req.body.credentials.username}, (err, user) => {
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: { global: "really???!!!" } });
  } 
  return res.status(200).json({data: user});
});
```